# Facebook Graph API: Accessing the URL of the larger version of a taggable_friend's picture

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, nsdictionary

I'm doing a `me/taggable_friends` Graph Request with several parameters, including `picture.type(large)`. According to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/picture/), that should be the correct parameter to get the largest version of the picture.

It seemingly does work. For example, the following code:

```
            facebookDict = result as! [String: AnyObject]

            for friendDictionary in facebookDict["data"] as! [NSDictionary] {
                let firstName = friendDictionary["first_name"] as? String
                let lastName = friendDictionary["last_name"] as? String
                let name = friendDictionary["name"] as? String
                let id = friendDictionary["id"] as? String

                if let picture = friendDictionary["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
                    print("\(firstName)'s picture URL is \(url)")
                    let height = data["height"]
                    print("Picture height is \(height)")
                    let friend = Friend(firstName: firstName!, lastName: lastName!, fullName: name!, id: id!, pictureURLString: url)
                    userTaggableFriends.append(friend)
                }

            }
```

The height printed to the console is 200 pixels (compared to using the parameter `picture` by itself with no type, which prints 50 pixels to the console). The issue is that the `url` field in that [`Profile Picture Source`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/) node always directs to a small version (50 pixels) of the picture. This is confusing to me, because the `height` lives in that same node, so presumably the `url` should direct to an image that has a height of 200 pixels. This isn't the case though, so I'm likely doing something laughably wrong.

How can I find the link to the larger version of the picture?

Comment: Should work this way. The image URLs returned seem to be different, too - but still deliver the same 50px by 50px small version. File a bug report and ask them to look into this, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @CBroe I'm checking out the bugs section of developers.facebook.com and it's looking like they've paused access to certain types of API data for non-active accounts (which I think mine counts as, since I only flipped it from Development Mode to Live recently). Seems like it has to do with the Cambridge Analytica thing https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/03/cracking-down-on-platform-abuse/